# Logging stack information

Tags: c#, .net, logging

Do you know any tool that can log what functions where called with what parameters ?

Not interested to write that code myself but thought that there maybe some tool that capable doing so ...

Thanks.

Comment: Profiles usually have that kind of information, although they are not for production use. What's the use case? I think that in the standard stack trace you miss the actual parameters value, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical example where aspect orient programming (AOP) can be used. Most AOP introductions show exactly that use-case (logging is the hello world of AOP). For example, have a look at [this PostSharp introduction](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/documentation/getting-started).

Answer (score 0):

Check [AQTime](http://www.automatedqa.com/products/aqtime)  function trace profiler.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Gibraltar](http://www.GibraltarSoftware.com/see/postsharp.aspx) too.  In particular, the [GFeature](http://www.gibraltarsoftware.com/Support/Documentation.aspx?Gibraltar.Agent.PostSharp~Gibraltar.Agent.PostSharp.GFeature.html) aspect is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Great News: GIBRALTAR is now FREE!!!
http://rocksolid.gibraltarsoftware.com/announcements/our-best-log-viewer-is-now-free

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Martin that aspect-oriented programming is a great way to automatically trace method execution and log all parameters. Some logging libraries already come with support for AOP frameworks. For example, [this article explains](http://blog.gurock.com/postings/aspect-oriented-logging-for-net-with-postsharp-and-smartinspect/848/) how to use PostSharp with our logging tool SmartInspect. There's also an [example for Unity](http://blog.gurock.com/postings/aspect-oriented-logging-for-net-with-unity-and-smartinspect/1386/).

Answer (score 0):

[Runtime Flow](http://www.svprogramming.net/runtime-flow/index.html) (developed by me) logs .NET function calls and with simple parameters like strings and numbers.